# Rails: Coffeescript click handler not being called

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, onclick, asset-pipeline

A coffeescript click handler I've binded to a play button in my rails app isn't being called, and neither is the onsubmit handler (so both listeners under `initialiseTimer()`aren't being called).

I've ran `console.log("MESSAGE")` before and after `initialiseTimer()` -- prints to the console both times. But that's not the case for the onsubmit and onclick handlers.

Any glaring causes for this? I'm new to coffeescript. Thanks!

**timestamps.coffee**

```
initialiseTimer = ->
    $('#counter').timer format: '%H:%M:%S'
    $('#counter').timer "pause"
    timerPaused = true 

resetTimerDisplay = ->
    $('#counter').timer "reset"

playOrPause = ->
    if timerPaused is true
        $('#counter').timer "resume"
        timerPaused = false
    else 
        $('#counter').timer "pause"
        timerPaused = true

$(document).ready ->
    initialiseTimer()

    $('#playback_buttons').click ->
      playOrPause()

    $('#new_timestamp').submit ->
        $('#counter').timer "pause"
        if $('#timestamp_seconds_elapsed').trim().val().length > 0
            seconds = $('#counter').data('seconds')
            $('#timestamp_seconds_elapsed').val(seconds)
            $('#counter').timer "reset"
            $('#counter').timer "pause"
        else
            $('#counter').timer "reset"
            $('#counter').timer "pause"
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<div class="new_timestamp_form">
  <div class="form_content">
    <h1>New Timestamp</h1>

    <%= render 'new_form' %>

    <%= link_to 'Back', @project %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**_new_form.html.erb**

```
<div id="timer_wrapper">
  <div id="counter"></div>
  <div id="playback_buttons">&#9658;</div>
</div>

<%= form_for [@project, @timestamp] do |f| %>
  <% if @timestamp.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@timestamp.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this timestamp from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @timestamp.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :seconds_elapsed %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :seconds_elapsed %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit'New Timestamp', :class => 'button' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What will happen if you put `console.log` before `playOrPause()` in a click callback? (also you have an inconsistent spacing there)

Comment: I don't think it's related to the problem, but you need to `return false` from the submit handler to prevent the default form submission.

Comment: @BroiSatse It gets printed out.

Comment: @bitfizzy - That mean that the callback is executed, but your method is not. Do you get any errors in the console? I think your closure is incorrect.

Comment: You should nuke turbolinks from your app to see if that's the problem. Remove the gem from your gemfile, and remove the directives from application.js an application.css.